# When is the transaction state set to restored in the updatedTransactions delegate method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver?

Tags: ios, swift, skpaymenttransaction

I've been testing code for in-app purchases, and I can't get the transaction state to set to restored in the updatedTransactions SKPaymentTransactionObserver delegate method when it's called. When does  that method call with that transaction state?

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        // Call the appropriate custom method for the transaction state.
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchasing:
            showTransactionAsInProgress(transaction, deferred: false)
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.deferred:
            showTransactionAsInProgress(transaction, deferred: true)
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
            failedTransaction(transaction)
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
            completeTransaction(transaction)
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:
            restoreTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: After you initiate the restore process by calling `restoreCompletedTransactios`

Comment: FYI - you can drop the use of `SKPaymentTransactionState` in all of your `case` statements.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a restored transaction if you call `restoreCompletedTransactions` on `SKPaymentQueue` and the user has restorable in-app purchases. See the [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) for complete details.

Comment: The documentation says that I can mark the product in App Store as restorable. I don't see that setting anywhere. Is that something that I can only do after I have passed the review by Apple for the product, or is that implicitly set when I select the product as non-consumable? I uninstalled my app and ran my project. The !!! paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished method was not called by payment queue like the documentation seemed to have said.

Comment: IAPs that aren't consumable are restorable